# Loop through list and copy cell to the right

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have inserted a command button on a worksheet that when pressed opens a password userform. when a password is entered this puts the cost centre number into a worksheet ***Executive Summary***.

The code below does not automatically update the pivot table as it requires the target cell to be changed.

How can I change the following code to update every time the target cell changes?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates
'when cell G1 is touched

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Executive Summary").PivotTables("ServiceCostAnalysis")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Cost Centre")
NewCat = Worksheets("Executive Summary").Range("G1").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
    pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just take Worksheet_Change instead of Worksheet_SelectionChange:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

This procedure executes every time a Cell in the Worksheet is changed.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Not sure why though which is rather annoying

Comment: Please remove the Not in your second code line and try it again.

Comment: Still Nothing. Its not debugging or anything its just not updating the pivot tables now.

Comment: So i recall correctly: You want your Pivot tables to be updated when the cell "G1" is changed?

Comment: Please set a few pause points in your Macro. Does the procedure even trigger, when you change something on your worksheet? When G1 is changed, does it proceed to the part after your if...intersect statement?

Comment: Will it have anything to do the `exit sub` at the end of `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`?

Comment: Or will it be affected by the fact that Cell `G1` is run using a `VLOOKUP` formula

Comment: I think this is why. Now you have two options: 1. Check within the intersect line if any of the cells within the vlookup source range of G1 is changed or 2. You always save G1 to a static value in the Worksheet change function and test, if it changed.

Comment: OK. So i have a list of 97 passwords on `Sheets("CC Number")` all in column `A:A`. When the password in entered, how do i make it go through the list until it finds the password entered? Then copy the cell to the right and paste that into `Sheets("Executive Summary").Range("G1)`

Comment: Where does the password to enter stand?

Comment: It is a `userform` that pop's up when the user selects an `ActiveX Command Button`. It will have to run off the submit button.